# How can I use scp to aquire a file from a server via a bastion with ssh forwarding?

Tags: ssh, scp, forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I'm wondering how to copy a file with scp (or a better way if possible) and allow ssh key forwarding.  I've read a lot of posts on how to do this closely, but not with ssh forwarding, or the -A equivalent we get with ssh.

Backstory - I have keys added with the method-

ssh-add mkey.pem
so that I can ssh into a bastion host with those stored keys like so...
[localhost]$ ssh -A user@bastion

...and then ssh into the server from the bastion, which will automatically use the ssh keys added from the localhost.
[bastion]$ ssh -A user@server

However, scp doesn't have an equivalent -A function to use a stored key from the localhost, which prevents you from having to store the key on the bastion.

What is the ideal approach to copying a file from a server via a bastion host that requires ssh keys for access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scp` supports passing options to `ssh` via the `-o` argument.

In this case, I think the best way to address this is to use `scp -o "ForwardAgent yes"`

Comment: ahh cool.  I'm not sure how to do that from localhost, but from the bastion I can do:  scp -o "ForwardAgent yes" user@server:/file .